# Standard Visitor visa refused (V4.2) for the second time

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I reapplied for a Standard Visitor visa to UK and the second attempt was refused, too. I don't object to a refusal but it should be consistent and correlated with the first refusal. The first application was refused because I am in my final year of study in a country other than my own home country, with a scholarship, and the ECO wanted me to further prove my circumstances in my country of study. This refusal was fine by me because being a student in a foreign country wasn't enough that I would come back to defend my thesis for my masters degree after my intended visit. I provided evidence of property back home a job, study leave letter, after study service bond, payslips, bank statements among others.

**Second refusal**:
[image: Second refusal letter]
[image: second refusal letter packpage]

Please look at the inconsistencies in the second letter and advise me accordingly.

1. I didn't ask for a four day entry clearance as stated in the second refusal.
2. I didn't say in the application I was going for research or study but rather a visit to see my fiancée's parents but whilst in UK, I would be writing my thesis, as the ECO states in the first refusal reason.
3. Were the first paragraph and the second paragraph of the second refusal written by the same ECO?
4. Look at the black circled lines to see the ECO's gaping flaw. He or she refuses a visa based on finances (how can I spend amount x on a four month trip) yet ECO writes I asked for four *days*?

Questions:

1. Can a face-to-face interview do any good?

I don't think I trust the system any more because where I applied from I just submitted papers and waited for a decision.

2. Was there really a reason for a refusal that weighed enough?

Comment: That's a lot of text and points . Could you highlight the specific problem? At present it looks to me like you're asking if there's a reason for a refusal, and clearly there was, as they rejected it. Arguing with them doesn't usually work well :/

Comment: Istanbul Gayot Flow..no am not arguing tbh,look thru the second overleaf of the rejection compare 4 months vs 4 day trip vs the amount i had as a budget.I couldn't apply to go to Uk for research not knowing who where how and when or the institution i will be conducting my research at.

Comment: The only misunderstanding there was is that the university stated research but this is internet based research or personal research.My letter from the university was so generic it gave the impression of a very different research hosted probably an institution.But this aside,never did i say am going to UK to do research but whilst in Uk,i will be writing my thesis which i have to come back to defend after my intended visit before a panel.WHY  VISIT vs WHILST IN UK mix up.

Answer (score 5):

**Can a face-to-face interview do any good?**

It's a theoretical question with no practical value.  A face-to-face interview isn't going to happen.  They stopped doing visit visa interviews a long time ago and there's no chance they will start doing it again before 2020, if then.  The reasons are...

1. The [hub and spoke programme](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tr4ZzUTs1eEC&pg=RA1-PA50#v=onepage&q&f=false) makes interviews impractical for
   many applicants;
2. Resources have been curtailed, and the training isn't available
   anymore; and
3. Nobody sees a benefit to it (*including the 'good guys'*);

**I don't think I trust the system any more because where I applied from I just submitted papers and waited for a decision.**

That's how the system works.  They go through your stuff and see if you qualify. The British Consulate General in Istanbul, for example, handles applicants in Georgia and Israel, some of those applicants can't even get in to Turkey.  But more to the point, would you rather get an answer in 15 days or wait around for 4 - 5 months to get an interview scheduled?

**Was there really a reason for a refusal that weighed enough?**

Based upon what they wrote, their rationale appears sound.   Interestingly, they refused you on [Paragraph V 4.2](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) rather than [Part 3](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-3-students) of the rules.  It suggests that they concluded that you were going to the UK to find work and settle with your fiance (or alternatively that the application in its entirety was misconceived and that you should have applied under Part 3 of the rules).  It's standard advice that after *the first refusal* the person should arrange a consultation with a member of the [UK Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/) so that these situations can be avoided.

You pointed out some sloppy composition errors on their part. Namely that they referred to four days instead of four months. Given that it's the second refusal, it will almost certainly get picked up for an audit when [the Chief](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/) does the next inspection of that post.  If so, he will spot it and the visa section will attract a comment (that's a bad thing).  It will not do you any good because it's poor composition and not poor decision-making.

Thanks for including a scan of your refusal notice, this allows us to get an answer out to you right away rather than closing the question.